# Google Cloud Api and Google Translate website giving different results. How to get same results?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translate, google-translation-api

I am facing an issue with google translation stuff. Google translate website is giving different results than Google cloud api. Is there any way that I can reproduce translate results of website in cloud api? Currently I am using following configuration in translation client:

```
model=translate.NMT
format_='text'
```

I am working in python.

Comment: Please post an example that gave you different results through the website and through the API.

Comment: Please provide a more complete example. The text you want to translate, original language and target language. I would be great if you could post the whole request. Also, which API are you using? There is AutoML translation and Translation API and you can see the differences [here](which-translation-product-and-model-is-right-for-you).

Comment: I've came across this problem several times during the short period of using the API. It feels like its quality is way lower than the web version!! 
as an example: